# Is it possible to create a field well with the numbers 1-100 in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am currently creating a pivot table in Quicksight which I am looking to create a Field Well with a series of numbers from 1 to 100. They should be static and not effect the data in the table though. I have managed to do this in PowerBI before using the GENERATESERIES function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 100 rows in your table, you could create a calculated field that uses [denseRank()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/denseRank-function.html) to assign every row a number from 1 to 100.  You would need to make sure you rank on field(s) that do(es) not have duplicates.  An index-based rank could work, for example.